# Supabase SQL question regarding foreign key

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I have two tables.

```
  Users
   - id (primary key)
   - firstName
   - lastName
   - userName
   - email
   
   Followers

   - user (foreign key to Users)
   - following (foreign key to Users)
```

I want to get all the non-followed users by the current users.

Here is my current query

```
let { data: followers, error } = await supabase
        .from("Users")
        .select("*, followers!inner(*)")
        .eq("followers.user", user.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the non-followed users by the current user, you can use a combination of not and in operators along with a subquery to exclude the users who are being followed by the current user.

Please try this

```
// Assuming user.id is the ID of the current user
let { data: nonFollowedUsers, error } = await supabase
  .from("Users")
  .select("*")
  .not("id", "in", supabase
    .from("Followers")
    .select("following")
    .eq("user", user.id)
  );

console.log(nonFollowedUsers);
```

Comment: Thank you. Here is an updated code that worked for me.

`
let { data: followers } = await supabase
        .from("followers")
        .select("following")
        .eq("user", user.id);

      let { data: nonFollowedUsers, error } = await supabase
        .from("Users")
        .select("*")
        .neq("id", user.id)
        .not(
          "id",
          "in",
          `(${followers?.map((follower) => follower.following).join(",")})`
        );

      console.log(nonFollowedUsers);
`